# How to remove a folder with a broken name?

Tags: windows, windows-live-mesh

I use Windows Live Mesh to keep my files backed up across many computers, but I have one folder (that I think came from a rar file), called `px 2` (with what appears to be a space at the end). This file is being a pest as mesh is always throwing up errors about it saying it contains invalid characters. When I try to delete or rename it, an error comes up saying "Could Not Find This Item", and the same goes for deleting the parent directory. I tried going into the folder from cmd, but when I do `DEL "*px*"` it still doesn't delete it. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this "folder"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command for deleting a directory is RMDIR or RD. I'm not sure if DEL is supposed to remove directories.

Comment: oooh, suddenly i'm feeling foolish